# How to create maker from value of string on Xamarin iOS Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Folks, How to create a marker from value of string on `Xamarin.iOS` Google Maps.

[image: string as icon marker]

On Android, I can use code below and I can create a icon with string, but on `iOS Xamarin`, how do create it?

```java
     IconGenerator icon = new IconGenerator(Context);
     Icon.SetContentRotation(-180); 
     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
          .SetIcon(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(icon.MakeIcon("350k")))
          .SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude))
          .Anchor(icon.AnchorU, icon.AnchorV)
          .SetRotation(180); 

     _map.AddMarker(markerOptions);
```

For example, on Android I instantiate the `IconGenerator` class and it makes possible to pass a value of string `"350k"`

But I have no idea to do that with `Xamarin iOS` project.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

If using Google Maps for iOS, there is a way to **[add a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#swift)** from google map official sample.

Here is the `swift` sample code for reference:

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10, longitude: 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it not produces a Marker labeled" Hello World", it produces a normal marker on the map. I need to produces a marker labeled from string.

Comment: @ThiagoHenrique Could you share which Nuget package of Google Map used ? I will check that.

Comment: I am using google maps 2.3.0. This code above produces a single marker but not but not produces what I want. I'm trying to create a marker from value of string and on Android I can do it using IconGenerator.

Comment: With oficial documentation, it creates only a single marker without text information




`var position = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127);              
 var london = new Marker() { Position = position };             
 london.Title = "London";             
 london.Snippet = "Population: 8,174,100";
 london.Map = Control as Google.Maps.MapView;`

Comment: @ThiagoHenrique The `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` nuget package of Xamarin Forms has the latest version is `3.5.0`. And you can have a look at its sample: https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps whether be helpful to achieve your wants.